# Overcome "Can not construct instance of InterfaceClass" without hinting the parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
InterfaceClass insert(@RequestBody InterfaceClass interfaceClass) {

    // Do something
}
```

The error I am getting is pretty straightforward and self-explanatory:

```
Can not construct instance of InterfaceClass: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information.
```

Basically, I need to tell Spring that I have a concrete implementation of `InterfaceClass`, `ClassImpl`.

I tried:

```
@JsonRootName("InterfaceClass")
public class ClassImpl implements InterfaceClass {
}
```

to no extent. I cannot use `@JsonTypeInfo` **as the parent interface class `InterfaceClass` should not be aware of `ClassImpl` and they are in different modules**. What I have also tried:

Implement `InterfaceClass` with abstract `AbstractClass` and put:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = AbstractClass.class)
```

on top of `InterfaceClass`. Then extend `AbstractClass` with `ClassImpl`. The error simply becomes:

```
Can not construct instance of InterfaceClass: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information.
```

Further tried:

```
public class ControllerClass<E extends InterfaceClass> {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    InterfaceClass insert(@RequestBody E interfaceClass) {
        InterfaceClass object = (InterfaceClass) interfaceClass;
    }
}
```

and this results in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to InterfaceClass
```

as expected.

I was really expecting Spring Boot to handle component discovery since there is only one concrete implementation of `InterfaceClass` or `AbstractClass`, which is `ClassImpl` in my classpath. Maybe I am doing something wrong? How can I overcome this, without explicitly hinting the `InterfaceClass` on where its implementation is (e.g. no `@JsonDeserialize`, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution 1 - Dynamically register subtypes

You can define the subtypes dynamically.

**1. On the interface, define a JSON field (@type) to be used as identifier:**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
public interface InterfaceClass {
}
```

**2. Add "@type" field to your JSON payload**

```
{
    ...
    "@type": "someName"
}
```

**2. Register the inteface's subtypes dynamically:**

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            objectMapper.registerSubtypes(ClassImpl.class);
            super.configure(objectMapper);
        };
    };
    return builder;
}
```

**4. Specify the "@type" name on your concrete class (optional):**

```
//Optional, otherwise uses the Simple class name (ie: 'ClassImpl')
@JsonTypeName("someName") 
public class ClassImpl implements InterfaceClass {
}
```

**5. Use can now use the interface with @RequestBody:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
InterfaceClass insert(@RequestBody InterfaceClass interfaceClass) {
}
```

---

## Solution 2 - Dynamically register a custom Deserializer

If adding a `@type` field isn't possible (or not wanted), you may also define a Custom Deserializer for your interface, which would in fact create a `ClassImpl`:

**1. Define a custom deserializer:**

```
class ClassImplJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ClassImpl> {
    @Override
    public ClassImpl deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return jp.readValuesAs(ClassImpl.class).next();
    }
}
```

**2. Dynamically set the custom deserializer:**

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.deserializerByType(InterfaceClass.class, new ClassImplJsonDeserializer());
    return builder;
}
```

**3. Remove @JsonTypeInfo from the interface:**

```
public interface InterfaceClass {
}
```